# Array script method validates radio button groups, but will not disable them. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, radio-button

I have a problem for which I made this demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Radio array looping</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="demoForm" method="post" action="whatever.php">
        <p>C-enabler:<input type="radio" name="en-disabler" value="someValue" onclick="enableCradios()"> &nbsp;
            C-disabler:<input type="radio" name="en-disabler" value="someOtherValue" onclick="disableCradios()">
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Question B1a:</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1a" value="0"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1a" value="2.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1a" value="5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1a" value="7.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1a" value="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Question B1b:</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1b" value="0"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1b" value="2.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1b" value="5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1b" value="7.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="B1b" value="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Question C1a:</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1a" value="0"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1a" value="2.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1a" value="5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1a" value="7.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1a" value="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Question C1b:</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1b" value="0"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1b" value="2.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1b" value="5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1b" value="7.5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="C1b" value="10"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        function disableRadios(array) {
            for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                var eachRadio = array[i];
                eachRadio.disabled = true;
            }
        }

        function disableCradios() {
            var groupNamesArray = ['C1a','C1b'];
            for (var i=0; i<groupNamesArray.length; i++) {
                var perGroup = groupNamesArray[i];
                var workingArray = demoForm.elements[perGroup];
                for (var i=0; i<workingArray.length; i++) {
                    var eachCgroup = workingArray[i];
                    disableRadios(eachCgroup);
                    //eachCgroup.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

See also this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXTBJ/). Note that I had to put the javascript in the HTML section, otherwise the fiddler wouldn't play. Clicking the C-disabler should disable the radio buttons of both C questions. It doesn't. And de-outcommenting `eachCgroup.disabled = true;` plus outcommenting `disableRadios(eachCgroup);` results in only the buttons of the first C question being disabled. The buttons of the second C question stay enabled then.

I have used that script method, which I would call the double array method, successfully in the validation, as can be seen [here](http://www.gezondezorg.org/upts.php). Works like a charm. But if I use the same method to disable the C section, it doesn't, or only half. Why would that be?

Comment: Always include the relevant code, markup, results, etc. **in** the question, don't just link, not even to jsFiddle. More: [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428).

Comment: Didn't know that. Included the code in the question.

Comment: *"I have used that script method, which I would call the double array method, successfully in the validation, as can be seen here."* Again: Include that information in the question. (I've removed my close-vote though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var groupNamesArray = ['C1a','C1b'];
for (var i=0; i<groupNamesArray.length; i++) {
    var perGroup = groupNamesArray[i];
    var workingArray = demoForm.elements[perGroup];
    for (var i=0; i<workingArray.length; i++) {
        var eachCgroup = workingArray[i];
        disableRadios(eachCgroup);
        //eachCgroup.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Using the **same variable name** in two nested `for` loops is wrong here … and nope, those are not two *different* variables named `i` here, because variables in JavaScript are [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

And you are using one “loop” to many here. `demoForm.elements[perGroup]` is a *NodeList* – and looping over that gives you access to the individual HTML elements in the NodeList already (which are the radio buttons of the specific name in this case) – **those** are what you want to set the `disabled` attribute on, but instead you are trying to “loop” over them again in your function `disableRadios` – only “looping over” *one individual* radio button does not make any sense.

*One* function like this is all you need here:

```
function disableCradios() {
    var groupNamesArray = ['C1a','C1b'];
    for (var i=0; i<groupNamesArray.length; i++) {
        var radioButtonsInGroup = demoForm.elements[groupNamesArray[i]];
        for (var j=0; j<radioButtonsInGroup.length; j++) {
            radioButtonsInGroup[j].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aXTBJ/2/

(I took the liberty of choosing different variable names here, as well as removing “unnecessary” variables.)

---

Both of those problems you could have figured out yourself quite easily, for example by making some debug outputs of your loop’s counter variables and the variables used to access the HTML elements via `console.log()` – so please do that next time, and train how to do such basic debugging yourself.

Comment: Of course! I missed the obvious. Thanks CBroe, really appreciate it. I tried to debug, but Firebug would either give no error report, or Firefox would have practical problems itself because of the script, possibly disabling Firebug. If there are any better debugging methods, please let me know. I have had no formal javascript training whatsoever, and find it a very difficult language. The reason for the individual button looping is that that is required in the validation of radio button questions. I just didn't think of it that in this case it is not required.

Comment: Well, the already mentioned `console.log` usually works fine for smaller stuff, like when you don’t know what value a variable has at a certain point (or you want to make sure it has the value you _think_ it has) – and for more complex situations, you can set a breakpoint in the script view yourself (or use a `debugger` statement), and then step through the script. There are some tutorials out there on how to do this, like http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging or http://thecodecentral.com/2007/08/01/debug-javascript-with-firebug

Comment: (And it doesn’t have to be Firebug of course, the developer tools in other browsers are quite capable as well [and usually the way they work is quite similar], so that’s more a matter of personal choice and taste.)